# How do you create test users for a Facebook app with type Native/Desktop?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In order to create test friends for my Facebook app I need an application access token, which I attempted to get using [this](http://codesoftly.com/2011/03/how-to-get-your-facebook-application-access-token.html) request however it returns the error, "The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app" which is supposedly caused by having your Facebook app type set to Native/Desktop, which mine is... so how else would I get the app access token?

Comment: Is it your intention to create test friends programatically? If not, you can create test users for your app by going to your app in developer's dashboard, settings, developer roles, and the bottom option is test users.. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I would like to create test accounts and assign friends programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a lot of cases you can probably switch your Facebook Application to being a `Web` app rather than `Native/Desktop`.  Check out the documentation on which to choose and you should be able to get your app access token after that.

P.S. Its fixed.