# Rails Devise Omniauth Facebook Client Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm having issues with getting saving a facebook login into my database. I'm getting the error in my browser.

```
Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials".
```

And this error is in my terminal. Any ideas? I've been browsing for 2 days and it's possible that the facebook api has changed. My only lead is that my app isn't using the client token at all.

And I don't know how to debug where user is nil or not. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback
code=AQCdbZAc0Nk6YS9_YNebSvNzRC9TQwWQbgolxpu2ZtNsxjP9nzECvkDGFQE71gxTTv86_ uc5mhkTzB4FBZinlDEaD0FFakDu3H-V7YmmYy_kcTRjxQTPucD-GnBlAiozDyQ3KLhnXE3nzWbcRsXwF_eFfc4kGUU8ww9Sgds906-w6lFppl4e78iudEfs9d-lhxgP_qa3_oUBfcG2fEiIYkMGYIOQIg_-9PWhgdrh_WT8qFyemN1qtkBuwE173UI-EodfrfGBTZVBBjM-U8n4rqeFX6gqgyNldMMa9gzXRVPuZ7cBEc1okzuQTgTAagz-KMmW0rNXgP81nWCVgqSPsX1O&state=c8957c4caba73271f3ed9a083412aa995afebf1ba2e63f50" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-27 22:11:16 -0800
I, [2016-02-27T22:11:16.190167 #9991]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2016-02-27T22:11:16.350628 #9991] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"GWdVBeCdl0k"}}
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQCdbZAc0Nk6YS9_YNebSvNzRC9TQwWQbgolxpu2ZtNsxjP9nzECvkDGFQE71gxTTv86_uc5mhkTzB4FBZinlDEaD0FFakDu3H-V7YmmYy_kcTRjxQTPucD-GnBlAiozDyQ3KLhnXE3nzWbcRsXwF_eFfc4kGUU8ww9Sgds906-w6lFppl4e78iudEfs9d-lhxgP_qa3_oUBfcG2fEiIYkMGYIOQIg_-9PWhgdrh_WT8qFyemN1qtkBuwE173UI-EodfrfGBTZVBBjM-U8n4rqeFX6gqgyNldMMa9gzXRVPuZ7cBEc1okzuQTgTAagz-KMmW0rNXgP81nWCVgqSPsX1O", "state"=>"c8957c4caba73271f3ed9a083412aa995afebf1ba2e63f50"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

Completed 302 Found in 211ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223634/how-do-you-create-test-users-for-a-facebook-app-with-type-native-desktop

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be 
 1. You used improper credentials for facebook developer api 
 2. The facebook login failed since you entered invalid email id or password.

Comment: I doubled check my credentials too many times. Does it have to be in development? Maybe I need to run a test app on the local server?